# How to fix the error: Could not make a connection to the IBM HTTP Administration server on node

Tags: websphere-8, ibmhttpserver

I have WebSphere 8.5 installed in local, I am trying to create a webserver to deploy an application (.ear) on it.

I use the WebSphere administration console to create the webserver, which is created successfully, but when I try to start it I get the following error:

Could not make a connection to the IBM HTTP  Administration server  on node localhost-nose/webserver1 (see the image below):

[image]

And when I check the HTTP server path, I find no `conf` folder

What could be the cause of this error and how to fix it ?

any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The IHS administration server, which serves as something like a node agent for unmanaged nodes, might not have been configured or started on the webserver system.

Since 8.0, associating IHS with the WAS Plugin and your application server is done through WCT/PCT.  One of the options in WCT/PCT is to configure IHS admin server.

One indication that you didn't run PCT would be that `$IHSROOT/conf/httpd.conf` does not contain a LoadModule for the WAS Plugin.

One indication that you didn't opt to configure the IHS admin server is that `$IHSROOT/conf/admin.conf` has @@ placeholder text in it.

If the admin server is configured, it needs to be started with

```
$IHSROOT/bin/adminctl start
```